# DataGrip / DBeaver cannot resolve table / column names

Tags: sql-server, database, jetbrains-ide, dbeaver, datagrip

I'm connected to my universities' SQL Server (Microsoft driver). I've tried using both DataGrip from JetBrains and DBeaver to connect. Everything seems to be fine when I execute a query. However, neither DataGrip nor DBeaver is giving me help with table or column names. In fact, DataGrip keeps telling me "Unable to resolve..." even if I type in the whole name (as I said the query executes just fine). Example screenshot:

[image]

I'll be really grateful for any suggestions.

Comment: Press More Schemas... what so you see?

Comment: @Porcupine, have you tried to choose any schemas for your data source?

Answer (score 11):

This issue is related to DataGrip's intellisense, a similar issue was posted to IntelliJ's community forms [here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000191404-DataGrip-Intellisense-sometimes-it-works-sometimes-it-doesn-t).

This answer relates to DataGrip 2017.1.5 (is likely applicable to other versions as well):

1. After creating the initial connection to your server, open the Database tool window using:

   - (ALT + F1) or
   - (View -> Tool Windows -> Database).
2. Listed beneath your server connection you will see a "Schemas..." item, double click it. This will expand into a list of all DB schemas you have access to on that server.
3. Select the schemas you are interested in, and additionally expand each DB schema to select all child schemas for that DB.
4. Click the refresh button in the schema selection window to synchronize your settings (two arrows pointing at each other in a circle).

   - [Image of Database Toolbar with DB/Schema selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLbgW.png)

Answer (score 1):

If they are DBO owned tables, qualify then as dbo.MyTable.  Datagrip seems to want a schema (DBO) for objects in order to use intellisense.